# Function for creating scoped beans causing UnsatisfiedDependencyException due to absence of singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I currently have the following code

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public A createScopedBeans(String s) {
   return new A(s);
}
```

This function above is being called multiple times and each time it creates a new bean/instance.
I also have another function as follows

```
@Bean
public Manager manager(List<A> list) {
    return new Manager(list)
}
```

So this should load all beans of type `A` and help create the bean of type `Manager`
However I get an error which says
`UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'createScopedBeans'`

Is it looking for a singleton bean of type `A` ?
How can I get around this ?

Full exception:

`2023-04-19 15:09:31.100 [main] [WARN ] o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'manager' defined in xxx.xxx: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'manager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'createScopedBeans' defined in yyy.yyy: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createScopedBeans' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: What's the *full* error message and stack trace?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question. I guess I dont have any bean of type `String` which can be autowired into `createScopedBeans`.

Comment: That is not how it works. You won't get a reference to all prototype scoped beans, if it would even be possible to create an instance, you would get a list of 1 bean. Each reference to bean of type A will lead to the creation of a new bean.

Comment: So if I want to autowire all instances `A` I need to create them as singleton beans ?

Comment: If you want all instances that is the way to go, as the context doesn't keep track of prototype scoped instances, as the lifecycle isn't controlled by the Spring container but the actual component that it is being injected into.